# Swift. Error updating UITextView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a UITableView in which multiple cells are registered.

```
private lazy var table: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    table.backgroundColor = .clear
    table.separatorStyle = .none

    table.dataSource = self.dataProvider
    table.delegate = self.dataProvider

    table.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    table.autoresizesSubviews = true
    table.estimatedRowHeight = CreateContentLayout.cellHeight

    table.register(CreateContentTextCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CreateContentTextCell.self.nameOfClass())
    table.register(CCOutlinedTextAreaCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CCOutlinedTextAreaCell.self.nameOfClass())
    table.register(CreateContentButtonCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CreateContentButtonCell.self.nameOfClass())
    table.register(CreateContentPhotoCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CreateContentPhotoCell.self.nameOfClass())
    table.register(CreateContentLableCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CreateContentLableCell.self.nameOfClass())
    table.register(CreatContetnAttachmentsCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: CreatContetnAttachmentsCell.self.nameOfClass())

    table.contentInset = .zero
    table.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    table.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    
    table.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)

    return table
}()
```

One cell is for entering text, the other for attaching an image.

The cell for entering text contains a UITextView. When typing text the UITextView and UITableViewCell increase the height, everything works fine.

```
private lazy var textField: MDCOutlinedTextArea = {
    let field = MDCOutlinedTextArea()
    let title: String
    
    field.minimumNumberOfVisibleRows = 1
    field.maximumNumberOfVisibleRows = .infinity
    field.textView.font = CreateContentLayout.lableAboutFont
    field.setOutlineColor(Color.gray, for: .normal)
    field.setOutlineColor(Color.blueGray, for: .editing)
    field.setTextColor(.black, for: .normal)
    field.setTextColor(.black, for: .editing)
    field.setFloatingLabel(Color.blueGray, for: .normal)
    field.setFloatingLabel(Color.blueGray, for: .editing)

    switch self.data {
    case let .subject(_, value, error), let .text(_, value, error), let .phone(value, error)/*, let .region(value, error)*/,
         let .recipeInfo(value, error), let .ingredients(value, error), let .email(value, error), let .communications(value, error):
        field.textView.backgroundColor = (value.isEmpty ? .clear : .white)
        field.textView.text = value
    default:
        break
    }

    
    field.textView.delegate = self
    
    return field
}()

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    let newHeight = (textField.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))).height

    if size.height != newSize.height {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        
        self.textField.snp.updateConstraints {
            $0.height.equalTo(newHeight)
        }
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }

    self.scrollToRect(textView)
}

func setupUI() {
self.contentView.addSubview(textField)
        
        self.textField.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.left.equalTo(BaseLayout.viewHorizontalPadding)
            $0.right.equalTo(BaseLayout.viewHorizontalPadding.negated)
            $0.top.equalTo(BaseLayout.viewHorizontalPadding)
            $0.bottom.equalTo(BaseLayout.viewHorizontalPadding.negated).priority(.low)
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(textDidChange(_:)),
            name: UITextView.textDidChangeNotification,
            object: self.textField.textView
        )
        
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
                                
        let newSize = self.textField.sizeThatFits(CGSize(
            width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - BaseLayout.viewHorizontalPadding * 2,
            height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        ))
        self.textField.snp.makeConstraints {
            $0.height.equalTo(newSize.height)
        }
```

However, when I add an image and the UITableView refreshes the cells, an extra area appears below.

More on video

[error video](https://youtu.be/UZM7t9HTf48)

[debug video](https://youtu.be/kvm_ITbMGTg)

Comment: What do you mean "it crashes". Do you get an exception message?  What line does it crash on?

Comment: No errors, sorry for the translation. An extra area appears below the UITextView. More details can be seen in the video

Comment: Please include screenshots.

Comment: Good day. I don't have enough reputation for posting images. I was only able to attach video links.